# Jupyter Notebook Cannot Access Desktop Files and Folders

Tags: terminal, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, macos-monterey

I recently bought a new M1 Pro Macbook with macOS Monterey. Migrated all my stuff from my previous Macbook Air over to it.

I opened my Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda but now, it cannot detect my Desktop files and folders (the Desktop folders are on the extreme right of the screenshot):

[image]

I have also went to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Files and Folders to check on the access and permissions, but nothing seems amiss:

[image]

Attaching the Jupyter terminal boot-up here as well just for reference:

[image]

Can anyone assist? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter can't cd outside of your `Users/user` path. However, you can change that folder in the `jupyter_notebook_config.py`. Look for the `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` entry to point to the desired working directory. You can create this config file from your shell via

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Small configuration is required to view these files on jupyter notebook.

1. Get the path of jupyter_notebook_config.py file.
   Below mentioned command can be used to find it -
   jupyter notebook --generate-config
2. open the file and search for c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir
   this might be configured to default value i.e. ''

   Reconfigure it and update path of directory contain code files,
   like -
   c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = /Volumes/Technical/Python

Comment: didn't work ...

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I recently did the same and moved all my files over to M1 Mac.  I have all existing notebooks in a folder and can save new notebooks and see those, but old ones are not visible in the folder via Jupyer?